# Excel - search for missing values and return these values based on 3 columns - MATCH/INDEX/IF combo?

Tags: excel, function, if-statement, indexing, match

This gets a bit too expert for me, hopefully one of  you can help me!

See the image for what I am trying to achieve. The red text shows what I want. **List3** contains all the possible values for **List1**. **List2** displays the currently active values for **List1**, and I want to return the missing values based on **List3**.

[image]

I'm guessing I'm looking at a MATCH/INDEX/IF function but I cannot figure this one out. Anyone out there willing  to give me a hand? <3 Thanks a bunch!

Comment: A reasonable solution will depend on whether the numbers are true numbers that have been formatted as `000` with a left alignment or text that looks like numbers.

Comment: Do I understand you correctly? You want to list all the values that are in List 3 but not in List 2?

Comment: Running a `MATCH` or `VLOOKUP` against an item **not** in a list will give you an `#NA` error.  You can then use `IFERROR` or `ISERROR` to react based on that.  If you want to get really fancy and make a list of it, you probably need to look at using `AGGREGATE` as either `SMALL` or `LARGE`

Comment: @Jeeped I can always change it to numbers, not really a problem since I can add the zero's later! But @Chroncidal already mentioned the usage of `IFERROR` or `ISERROR` should tackle this problem. Thanks for the replies so far!

Comment: OK, it sounds like you have it handled.

Comment: Possible method of implementation 1. Create an array (stack) that will contain all the possible values. 2. Create a second two dimensional array, that will contain all the current values for ID, eg. `array2=[4][003, 012, ...]`  and `array2=[447][003, 012, ...]` you get my point. 3. Afterwards, you would just loop for each second dimension and through all it's elements comparing it with the first array. 'Popping' anything out of first array that's there, leaving you with an array that would result the missing - unused - numbers. Then re-fill the array of all possible numbers and loop to next ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this formula in F4 and fill down.

```
=INDEX(C:C, AGGREGATE(15, 7, ROW(C$2:C$11)/NOT(COUNTIFS(B:B, C$2:C$11, A:A, E4)), COUNTIF(E$4:E4, E4)))
```

Of course, this formula is dependent on the list of 'numbers' in E4:E7 being accurate and sufficiently populated to catch all missing entries.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Reference the image below. Use this formula to get the number missing:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A2:A40<>A1:A39))*ROWS(C2:C12)-ROWS(A2:A40)
```

Change `A40` to the last cell of your data in column A and `A39` to the *second to last* cell.

Then enter this helper column as an array formula (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>) into a 1-column range with the same number of rows that the formula above returns (it encodes the missing pairs into a single number). I entered it into `D4:D8`:

```
=SMALL(IFERROR(0>MATCH(INDEX(A2:A40,INDEX(SMALL(IF(A2:A40<>A1:A39,ROW(A2:A40)-ROW(A1)),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&SUM(--(A2:A40<>A1:A39))))),INT((ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&ROWS(C2:C12)*SUM(--(A2:A40<>A1:A39))))-1)/ROWS(C2:C12))+1))&INDEX(C2:C12,MOD((ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&ROWS(C2:C12)*SUM(--(A2:A40<>A1:A39))))-1),ROWS(C2:C12))+1),A2:A40&B2:B40,0),INDEX(SMALL(IF(A2:A40<>A1:A39,ROW(A2:A40)-ROW(A1)),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&SUM(--(A2:A40<>A1:A39))))),INT((ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&ROWS(C2:C12)*SUM(--(A2:A40<>A1:A39))))-1)/ROWS(C2:C12))+1)*ROWS(C2:C12)+MOD((ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&ROWS(C2:C12)*SUM(--(A2:A40<>A1:A39))))-1),ROWS(C2:C12))+1),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&SUM(--(A2:A40<>A1:A39))*ROWS(C2:C12)-ROWS(A2:A40))))
```

Again, change `A40` to the last cell of your data in column A and `A39` to the *second to last* cell.

Next, enter this formula into `E4` and fill down:

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$40,INT(D4/ROWS($C$2:$C$12)))
```

Finally, enter this formula into `F4` and fill down:

```
=INDEX($C$2:$C$12,MOD(D4,ROWS($C$2:$C$12)))
```

[image]