# get values of a range that are not in another range

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula, formula

Excel question: I'm looking for a way to list all elements in a range, except those that are in another range.

For example: If A1:A5 = [1,2,3,4,5] and B1:B3 = [4 2 1]

I want to have returned an array [3 5].

The second range will never contain any values other than those in A1:A5 in my case, but a general solution would also be nice.

I do not know how to use VBA and would prefer a classical formula. Any ideas?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51061884/excel-search-for-missing-values-and-return-these-values-based-on-3-columns-m/51063693#51063693

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try,

```
=INDEX(A:A, AGGREGATE(15, 7, ROW($1:$5)/NOT(COUNTIF( B$1:B$3, A$1:A$5)), ROW(1:1)))
```

[image]